# trap "ctrl-c" to kill background shell

Tags: trap

### background

bash 4.2

I have two files `envar` and `main.sh`

**envar**

```
...

# displays a spinner so that user knows the job is under processing.
spinner()
{ 
  spin='-\|/'
  i=0
  while kill -0 $1 2>/dev/null
  do
    i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
    printf "\e[1;33m"
    printf "\r${spin:$i:1}"
    printf "\e[m"
    sleep .1
  done
}
...
```

**main.sh**

```
source envar

very_slow_and_dangerous_function &
pid=$!
spinner $pid
echo "$jobs done"
```

---

**The problem**

When someone press `ctrl-c` during `spinner $pid` the background shell becomes motherless.
I want both shells killed when `ctrl-c` or any other force signals happen.

How do I use Trap here?

Comment: How do you run these scripts? You mention `bash` but don't show a shebang or mention if you launch with `bash main.sh` or `sh main.sh` or something else. `source` is not portable, it's a bashishm for the standard `.` command. I doubt it will be relevant, but you never know.

Comment: @terdon I use shebang `#!/bin/bash`. Thank you for the insight I didn't know source was bash only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try trapping `SIGINT` to `kill 0` in `envar`:

```
$ cat envar
trap "kill 0" SIGINT
spinner()
{ 
  spin='-\|/'
  i=0
  while kill -0 $1 2>/dev/null
  do
    i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
    printf "\e[1;33m"
    printf "\r${spin:$i:1}"
    printf "\e[m"
    sleep .1
  done
}
```

This will make the subshell also die. I tested with:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

## source your function file
. envar

sleep 600 &
pid=$!
spinner $pid
echo "$jobs done"
```

Running this and killing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> results in:

```
$ foo.sh
/^CTerminated
$ pgrep -c sleep
0
```